# processing 5 items at a time from a list or recordset

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list of member IDs that I need to loop over and do some processing against each id.

I currently loop over each ID and do some processing against each ID in a cfthread for each id.  The problem I have is that it is creating too many threads, so I figured I can process about 5 items within each thread.  But I am struggling to work this one out.

I'm looking for something similar to RoR's in_groups_of method.  So I want to break the list, of say, 100 list items, into 20 smaller lists of 5 in each list,  passing each smaller list into the cfthread, rather than one item at a time.

I'm sure this is simple to do, but I just can't work out how I would do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about turning the list into an array:

Obviously this is the very bare bones, but it could provide a start:

```
<cfscript>
    myArr = listToArray(myList);

    for(i=1;i<arrayLen(myArr);i+5){

        //need to do some checking to confirm that myArr[i+1] etc exist
        processFive(myArr[i],myArr[i+1],myArr[i+2],myArr[i+3],myArr[i+4],myArr[i+5]);
    }
    function processFive(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5){
        //spin up thread and do processing...

    }

</cfscript>
```

Comment: BennyB, working with arrays was certainly the trick.  I started with your approach along with arraySlice udf (http://www.cflib.org/udf/arraySlice).. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Curse my inability to comment!  I like BennyB's answer, but you could still have many threads.  What if you started some threads, and had the threads take 5 items off the array at a time?